# "Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the GLKit plug-in"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5

Kind of a weird problem with xcode that just popped up overnight, I can't get into any part of it without an error coming up. With GLKit in: /system/library/Frameworks/glkit.framework I'll get the error:
Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the GLKit plug-in". (I've never touched the frameworks before, so this plugin was already in that location). 
If I remove the plugin trying to open xcode creates the error "Xcode quit unexpectedly."
I can't click on Report... because it doesn't take me anywhere or show me any logs anymore, but when I did see the log the very first time I remember seeing something about Spritekiteditor and libdyld.dylib if that helps at all?  
Also it's the latest version, I've deleted and redownloaded the app to no effect, and I have no projects, they were all deleted to see if they were causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

probably has to do with your computer version.

Be sure your mac is one of these versions:

Mac OS X 10.3 (Version 1.x)

Mac OS X 10.4 (Version 2.x)

Mac OS X 10.5 (Versions 2.5, 3.0, 3.1)

Mac OS X 10.6 (Versions 3.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2)

Mac OS X 10.7 (Versions 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6)

OS X 10.8 (Version 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 5.x)

OS X 10.9 (Version 5.x)

Comment: I'm on the latest OS X 10.9 so that's okay. Plus it was working for weeks before these crashes. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following folders and restart Xcode:

- /Library/Caches/com.apple.DeveloperTools*
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist

Comment: Neither of those existed for me :(